# Using Flow js, where do you keep your Type Aliases?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm new to using Flow js, and find myself creating a lot of custom type aliases for the different API call responses and other functions. Currently I keep the type alias in the same file where I need it, and export it if I need it elsewhere in the program. But, I'm quickly finding this to become unwieldy / messy. Is there a certain recommended structure of how to organize all of the type aliases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flow-typed` directory to define global types and modules like explained in [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/). Other way would be to make some index file on top of some folder structure where you would export all related to this directory types. In my project I have global redux types declared in `flow-typed` directory and other types exported from `commons` directory.